# solaris recv infinite receiving

Tags: c, solaris, recv

When you run this code, the response does not come.
Soket is a state of being connected.
So forever is in the standby state return value without not.
please help me.

```
...
sock = socket(PF_INET, protocol, 0);
...
char recv_data[102400] = {0,};

while ((size=recv(sock,recv_data,102400-1, 0)) > 0){
    // some code
}
...
```

> OS : SunOS xname 5.10 Generic_147440-12 sun4u sparc
>   SUNW,Sun-Fire-15000

Comment: What is 'protocol'?  What do the server logs say?

Comment: protocol = #define SOCK_STREAM SOCK_STREAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the socket is blocking.

```
int noblock(int fd)
{
      int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
      if (flags < 0) return 0;
      flags = (blocking) ? (flags&~O_NONBLOCK) : (flags|O_NONBLOCK);
      return (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Use this to set the socket to non-blocking.  When there is no data to read, `recv()` will return a -1
and set `errno` to `EWOULDBLOCK`

See if those changes get you past your current problem.

You really should be checking the return codes of all you calls